# WPF WebBrowser OnTitleChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

i am using System.Windows.Controls.Webbrowser class in my C# app.
I want to recognize if the document title changes.

Therefore i listen on the LoadComplete Event and getting the title

```
    public void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic doc = browser.Document;
        setTitle(doc.Title);
    }
```

The problem now is, that the title could change during loading. In this case the LoadCompleted event would not fire. 
Next problem is. I have a html application inside which navigates through javascript functions in the application. In case of using these javascript links, the event would not fire, too.

I am looking for an event like [OnTitleChange from CHtmlView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4s847x4k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (c++)
Is there a possibilty to solve my issue?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported by the WPF webbrowser.

You can use windows forms interop to show a windows forms webbrowser control then subscribe to the DocumentTitleChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for me:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate(URL);
        browser.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(browser_DocumentTitleChanged);

        WindowsFormsHost winFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
        winFormsHost.Child = browser;
        AddChild(winFormsHost);

public void browser_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  setTitle(browser.DocumentTitle);
}
```